# Set fixed divs regardless of the size of the content

Tags: html, css

I'm developing an item list that is filled dinnamically with some data that is getting from a controller.
I had a problem when the data is shown because I need to show it into two columns (called "record_left_content" and "record_right_content"), but when the obtained text is too long, the two columns are merged into one.

Someone knows how to positionate the both colums in a fixed way regardless of the size of the text/content ?
[image]
[image]

Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-9" id="middle_column">
 <div class="text-center text-muted" t-if="not education_timetable_ids">
  <h1>No timetables found</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="text-center text-muted" t-else="">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
   <li t-foreach="education_timetable_ids" t-as="timetable" t-attf-class="media">
    <div itemscope="itemscope" class="media-body" itemtype="https://schema.org/learningResourceType" >
     <h4>
      <a t-attf-href="/" itemprop="url" onclick="return false"><span itemprop="schedule"><t t-esc="timetable.display_name" /> </span></a>
     </h4>
     <div id="record_left_content">
      <div>
       <span t-if="timetable.academic_year_id" class="badge badge-info">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o" role="img" aria-label="Academic year" title="Academic year"></i>
        Academic year: 
        <t t-esc="timetable.academic_year_id.name" />
       </span>
      //more code
     <div id="record_right_content">
     //more code
     </div>
```

```
.media {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    margin: 10px;
}
#record_left_content {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20%;
}

#record_right_content {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: why don't you use **max-width**

Comment: Tried this property, but when the text is too long it goes out of the div @SameerKhan

Comment: I created a **jsfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/sameerthekhans/3rbnho5k/, but your html is incomplete could you please update ?.